# Receiving Chat inbox message because a user has the same name in lowercase

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

Since today or yesterday my Inbox is receiving more and more chat replies, because someone has the name "mark" lowerCase 'M'.

User [mark](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4604744/mark)

User [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424226/mark)

[image]

Comment: related: [*name change to "Tim something"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/158100)